Syntax for Multiple Index Entries in Sphinx
I would like to know if there is a way to add multiple index entries in Sphinx.
In the tutorials, I've found that only two entries can be added using the format
.. index:: main_entry; sub_entry
However, I am looking for a method to include more than two entries, similar to LaTeX's approach with
\index{main_entry!sub_entry!sub_sub_entry}
Is there a way to achieve this in Sphinx?

I've tried that, but it does not add a sub_sub_entry correctly. Instead, it creates a main entry and a sub entry "sub_entry; sub_sub_entry"

"I've tried that..." - What have you tried?

Is there nothing here that does what you want? https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#index-generating-markup

In the link you shared, there is an option pair: module; sys
or triple: module; search; path but this is useful only to make pairs and triples (like synonyms). This is not what I'm looking for.

The first comment was a reply to a guy how asked if I've already tried to do .. index:: main_entry; sub_entry; sub_sub_entry
